# "Pylint not found" at mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

Hi i'm trying to install pylint for my vscode and my terminal seems to install successfully but leaves lists of warnings like:

```
WARNING: Target directory /Users/Sophie/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/astroid already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement
```

and when i type `which pylint` it returns `pylint not found`. Also, here are some information about my python below

```
which python -> /usr/bin/python
which python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3
which pip -> /usr/local/bin/pip
which pip3 -> /usr/local/bin/pip3
python --version -> Python 2.7.16
python3 --version -> Python 3.8.5
```

Please let me know if I have made mistakes, thank you

Comment: Install it how?

Comment: What exact command are you using to install `pylint`?

Comment: i used `pip3 install pylint`

Comment: @Soyoung Park What environment are you currently using in VSCode? And when you use "pip3 list", does "pylint" appear in the list?  It will be better solved if you could provide us with details of the steps that can reproduce this problem.

Comment: @JillCheng I'm not sure what environment you actually mean but pip3 list does not show pylint in the list and shows this messages too - `WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.`

Comment: plust installing pylint from vs code returns `ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'` as well

Comment: @Soyoung Park It is recommended that you use "pip --version" to check whether pip is available in the current VSCode python interpreter. When pip is available, we can use pip to install pylint. In addition, for the VSCode environment you can refer to: [Python environments in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)